# About Scheduler at Spring 4xx Version

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, shedlock

My application is using spring 4.0.0. I'm trying to write a scheduler in a distributed system. My application is working on multiple servers and my database is also running at multiple servers.

I'm trying to achieve: **My scheduler will run on one server only.**

I tried two approaches:

1. Profiling: Make a different profile and deploy it in any server.

   But I don't want a different-different profile for different-different servers.
2. Shedlock

   Shedlock does not support spring 4xx version.

Kindly suggest a better approach

Comment: So basically the solution you should be using, profiles or external configuration is the one you don't want to use.

Comment: yes, @M.Deinum I don't want to depend on multiple configurations.

Comment: You don't have to. You can have it depend on a single property which can be set in the environment. Basically disable jobs by default only enable when this property is set to `true` (or something along those lines). The same would work for profiles, enable only when a certain profile is active. You don't have to have seperate configuration just enable an additional profile. That is what it is designed for.

Comment: So According to you just add a new separate configuration say "conf File 2".deploy all with previous conf file (say conf 1) and in one server deploy with conf1 + conf2. Am I right??

Comment: No that isn't what I'm saying. Deploy everything with the same configuration and override 1 property (or enable a profile) to switch on tasks. You don't need seperate config files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use old version of ShedLock https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock/issues/299